# Can't figure it out; How to sort data into specific rows in excel

Tags: excel

Appreciate all the help I can:

So I have got hundreds upon hundreds of rows of data (more being addeded daily)

Basically, I'm getting data that ranges from 1-80, but I want to be able to place that data into;

For example, I want 7 to be placed in 7, 10 to be placed in 10, 65 to be placed in row 65.

I can do this manually, but there has to be a code, forumla, script or something that would make it instant right?

I appreciate all the help or any advice that you can give!

[image]

Comment: please post your desired output also. that will be helpful for us to understand

Comment: And tell us if you want just numeric data to be moved or if there is anything more

Comment: How are you entering the data into Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim arr, item
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")  'change Sheet3 to your data sheet
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                'get last row with data in Column1
        lastCol = .Cells(lastRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  'get last column with data in last row
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(lastRow, 1), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))  'set range for last row
        arr = rng.Value                                                 'put range values in an array
        rng.ClearContents                                               'clear last row
        For Each item In arr                                            'loop through each item in array
            .Cells(lastRow, item).Value = item                          'write item values into cell
        Next item
    End With
End Sub
```

***Output :***

[image]

This code will work for the last row with data in `Column A`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place each random number into it's corresponding column, please use formula below. `=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(CF$1,$A2:$CB2,0),"")="","",CF$1)`. Enter this formula in cell `CF2` and drag below whole table. Enter all your random raw values in columns `A:CB`(80 columns in total). You should get this result (please note that I've hidden couple of columns):[image]

Comment: Maybe ISERROR is better, like =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(CF$1,$A2:$CB2,0)),"",CF$1) or ISNUMBER =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(CF$1,$A2:$CB2,0)),CF$1,"")